# Should java give an error message about assigning a private variable from inner classes?

Tags: java, closures, inner-classes

I have some code like this:

```
class Outter {
    private Bar bar;

    [...]

    public update() {
        provider.doUpdate(new IListenner() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Bar bar) {
                Outter.this.bar = bar;
                // Here, Outter.this.bar.equals(bar) is false.
            }
        }
    }

    [...]

}
```

I think this has to do with the way Java capture variables in my closure, capturing a `bar reference` instead of capturing the `Outer` instance reference. If I write:

```
Outter self = Outter.this;
self.bar = bar;
```

it works, forcing Java compiler to store a reference to my `Outter instance` instead of a reference to the `bar` field in its closure.

The right way to do this is probably to use a `setBar(Bar bar)` in Outter and call it from the inner class.

But as it don't work, why the Java compiler don't give an error message about it ? Like `bar should be final` when capturing the non-final reference ?

I compile this using Android Studio 1.2.1.1, not tried in other contexts, don't know how Android Studio actually compile Java. My JRE seems to be Java 1.7.0 from the openjdk-7-jre-headless Debian package version `7u79-2.5.5-1~deb8u1`.

Comment: It doesn't behave like that for me: http://ideone.com/B4CoQs  Could you create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: I tried to rollback my code as it was this morning, but I'm not able to reproduce this. We were two witnesses of this (I called another dev to review me while it was happening) so I didn't dreamt it :-P

Comment: Let's just hope someone will found the same problem and found this same thread to add information :o( until then we should just ignore this )o:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you're reporting sounds very strange. First, I can't reproduce it with neither ECJ nor with javac 7. (See http://ideone.com/B4CoQs)

The difference in bytecode between

```
Outter.this.bar = bar;
```

and

```
Outter self = Outter.this;
self.bar = bar;
```

is just an extra `astore_2`/`aload_2`, which basically corresponds to a no-op.

I encourage you to check your assumptions. Perhaps you have a buggy implementation of `Bar.equals` that causes the confusion.

> Like bar should be final when capturing the non-final reference?

Fields aren't captured in that sense. Fields can be accessed from inner classes / methods without being final.

Comment: Bar.equals was just an example, but objects were actually different (different data in it, different address in memory) I was debugging the code at the time.

Comment: As I'm unable to reproduce it for now I can only think of the compiler trying to optimize something leading to this situation sometimes... :( I'm a newcomer to java so I don't play like you to read the compiled code ^^

Comment: Well, if you say it helps to split it up in two statements, there's something else going on. (I.e. it doesn't have to do with inner classes / closures. Take my word for it. I work as a Java-compiler dev at Oracle :-) With the link in my answer and the bytecode disassembly I think I've proven this beyond doubt. Feel free to accept the answer if you agree.

Comment: I accept as an answer as I can't reproduce it and you shed a lot of light on it ;)